# Adding hadoop-aws module to pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to add "hadoop-aws" jar package to my pyspark installation. However, my connection to the internet on that machine is restricted. Therefore pyspark cannot automatically add "hadoop-aws" to the jars using the command :

`pyspark --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.x.x`

So how can I manually add this jar file to my pyspark environment ?

I read its possbible to place the jar file under

`./venv/lib/python3.x/site-packages/pyspark/jars`

But this does not work as expected. When I start pyspark in this environment, it looks for the jar package in the default cache locations  `/root/.ivy2/jars` and `/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop`.

If pyspark cannot find the package here, it tried to download the package from central repos, which is not possible in my case because of Network restrictions (I suspect so).

P.S. I use jdk 11 and pyspark 3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `spark.jars` in order to load it from your chosen path (doesnt have to be one of the ones you mention... any path will do)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .config("spark.jars", "/path/to/hadoop-aws-3.x.x.jar"")
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("Example - Add a JAR file")
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

You can check if its there by running this code.

```
# Get the configurations
conf = spark.sparkContext.getConf()

# Print them
for k, v in conf.getAll():
    # print(f"{k} = {v}") # run this if you want to see all confs 
    if k == "spark.jars":
        print(f"{k} = {v}")
```